# Conceptual questions relevant to least square projection.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

This is an excerpt from Gilbert Strang's Linear algebra. Suppose I have a collection of points $(t,b) \in R^2$, $\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,2)\}$. I want to find a least square that gives me the least square.

Of course, I may set up a system of equation:
\begin{align*}
  C + D &= 1 \\
  C + 2D &= 2 \\
  C + 3D &= 2,
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}C \\ D\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$,

and find $C, D$ that is an orthogonal projection of $(1,2,2)$ onto span of two vectors. Let $U:= span\{(1,1,1), (1,2,3)\}$.

I am confused why this such projection gives minimization of the least square line. Our original problem is relevant to projecting 2-dimensional vectors to a 1-dimensional subspace, and our question is to find such 1-dimensional subspace. Now, we have another problem that involves a projection of a vector $v \in R^3$ to a 2-dimensional subspace $U$. What's the connection between least square line and projection? Why is it an equivalent problem?

Furthermore, if there are $n$ points of the form $(t, b)$, then I may set up a system of linear equation $Tx = y$, where $T \in L(R^2, R^n)$. I can define adjoint $T' \in L(R^n, R^2)$ characterized by: $\langle T\vec x, \vec y\rangle_n = \langle \vec x, T'\vec y\rangle_2$. Strang uses transpose matrix to define a orthogonal matrix, and I am trying to reinterpret everything he does in terms of inner product (for example, what he defines as $x^TA^T \vec b$ is just an inner product $\langle b, Ax\rangle$). After all, transpose matrix is just a matrix representation of adjoint with respect to some orthornormal basis.

Comment: “Our original problem is relevant to projecting 2-dimensional vectors to a 1-dimensional subspace, and our question is to find such 1-dimensional subspace.” is totally incorrect. That’s not what “projection” means and it’s not what the “original problem” is. The “original problem” is to find $c$ and $d$ that minimize the sum of squared errors $(c+d-1)^2+(c+2d-2)^2+(c+3d-2)^2$ (and by doing the algebra you can see the same solution is given by projecting $(1,2,2)$ onto $U$). That’s *not* projecting $(1,1)$ etc onto a line.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I see. Here, we are taking $L^2$ norm. Do I get the same $c,d$ for every $p \in [1, \infty]$?

Comment: No, the solution is different for different $p$.